# cant convert allure reports into html

Tags: python, allure, python-behave

I want to convert my JSON reports into HTML but facing this error. I have added them into environment variables.

> allure : The term 'allure' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I can't convert them into HTML file.

Comment: Is `allure` installed and added to system's path ?

Comment: yes i have seen mu;ltiple videos and added it into the path

Comment: Clearly something in your setup is not correct. I would try walking through the steps again, checking each step carefully.

Answer (score 0):

you need install jdk, then install allure-commandline-2.13.2,finally install Allure-Behave.

hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. I had not installed allure. Try downloading the allure zip file https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases

Unzip the file and add its path to the system's env variable.

Open a new cmd and navigate into your project just before the features directory run the command

`allure serve <folder_name>` the folder name is where your json reports are.